# Using regression to forecast timeseries with Weka

Tags: python, r, statistics, weka

I need to build a model using Weka to forecast the future trends of a system
The data feeds I am getting is a vector that comes in pairs. Example

```
    1001,1002,1160,101,111,29-12-2016  
    1011,1003,1180,102,122,21-11-2016 
    1101,1004,1110,103,123,27-06-2016 
    1111,1001,1110,104,111,20-12-2016  
    1011,1009,1110,105,114,15-09-2016  
    1101,1102,1150,102,113,01-03-2016 
    1111,1302,1120,107,118,08-05-2016 
    1111,1072,1130,101,122,12-10-2016
```

I have up to a million data set coming in from the unit on monthly basis.
I need to build a cluster to find partern on the data set based on the day of the month.
Secondly I need to try and predict the what the next daily average of the vector  could be based on test data.
Example given 2 sample data set. If I validate my sample with the model. I need to get the result as a confidence level or the probability of the vector belonging to a particular cluster or being the next result set.

```
    1001,1002,1160,101,110,29-12-2016 --> will give a confidece of 0.91  
    1111,1000,1111,102,122,21-11-2016 --> will give a confidece of 0.652
```

I need to use python and Wake library to run the request. If possible. 
Could any other system like R do the Job?

Comment: I am looking for an example or tutorial on how I can build the code.

Comment: This is closer to what I am looking for [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432781/how-to-use-weka-for-predict-results)